# How to pass String variable as a condition into DataFrame Filter?

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, filter

I want to filter out data from `DataFrame` `df` on the basis below condition. Due to few requirement I need to pass this condition using Configuration file (or as a String Variable).

**DataFrame df**

```
+----+------+----+-----+
|  Id|  Name|City|State|
+----+------+----+-----+
|   1|   ABC| ADI|  GUJ|
|   2|   BCD|null|  MAH|
|   3|  null| ADI|  GUJ|
|   4|  AFDS| DEL|  DEL|
|null|  null| PUN| null|
|   6|   DSF| MUM|  MAH|
|   7|DSFDFS|null|  RAJ|
|   8|  null| PUN|  MAH|
|   9|   FDA| JAI|  RAJ|
|  10|  DFAD|null|  GUJ|
|  11|  null|null| null|
|  12|  null|null| null|
+----+------+----+-----+
```

**Condition:**

```
col("State").isNull && (col("City").isNull || col("Name").isNull)
```

I have checked that `filter` accept String condition but it is not working with `isNull` in above condition.

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use SQL in filter:

```
filter("State IS NULL AND (City IS NULL OR Name IS NULL)")
```

Answer (score 0):

Would this help:

```
val queryToExeFromConf = "SELECT * FROM MyTempView WHERE State IS NULL AND (City IS NULL OR Name IS NULL)"
df.createOrReplaceTempView("MyTempView")
val filteredDF = df.sparkSession.sql(queryToExeFromConf)
```

Answer (score -1):

I assume you want to filter out the records where 'State' and 'City/Name' are null. Try the below solution -

```
df.filter(!col("State").isNull && !col("City").isNull.or(col("Name").isNull))
```